# Rails 3 query with has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following models: `recommendations`,`ratings` and `product`.  A `product` `has_many` `recommendations`, a `recommendation` `has_many` `products`, a `recommendation` `has_many` `ratings` and a `rating` `belongs_to` a `recommendation`.
I am currently using the following query to find all records in my index:

```
@recommendations = Recommendation.find(:all, :joins => :products, :conditions => ["product_id = ? AND rating_set = ?", (params["product_id"]), (params["rating_set_id"])])
```

and to get each records recommendations rating, I have another scope with I call in my view.

What do I set `@recommendatons` to to get back all recommendations and ratings that are found by a specific `product_id` and `rating_set`?

I tried:

```
    Recommendation.find(:all, :joins => :products,:include => :ratings, :conditions => ["product_id = ? AND rating_set = ?",2086981,40]).each do |rec|
puts rec.rating
end
```

Which was printed `Nil`.

**UPDATED WITH MODELS:**

Product

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :product_recommendations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :recommendations, :through => :product_recommendations
end
```

Recommendation

```
class Recommendation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_recommendations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :products, :through => :product_recommendations
  has_many :ratings
end
```

Rating:

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recommendation  
end
```

This is the result I need(This only works if the rating has been created, which is why I cant use it):

```
@recommendations = Rating.find(:all, :conditions => ["product_id = ? AND rating_set = ?", (params["product_id"]), (params["rating_set_id"])])
```

What Im querying:
I need to find all Recommendations where product_id and rating_set = ?, ? and given that, find all ratings that belong to each of those recommendations.

**Update**

I am able to get back all ratings that belong to a recommendation using the following query:
`Recommendation.joins(:product_recommendations).includes(:ratings).where(:product_recommendations => { :rating_set => 48, :product_id => 2144877 })`
When I loop through the array of ratings returned, they are not scoped to the correct rating_set, but rather I get all ratings for all rating_sets the belong to a specific recommendation. How can I get back an array of ratings for for each recommendation AND rating_set.

Comment: What does `Recommendation.find(:all, :joins => :products,:include => :ratings)` return?

Comment: It returns the following query: `SELECT recommendations.* FROM recommendations INNER JOIN product_recommendations ON product_recommendations.recommendation_id = recommendations.id INNER JOIN products ON products.id = product_recommendations.product_id`.

Comment: I meant how many rows?

Comment: ~2.4 million rows returned.

Comment: How many for `Recommendation.find(:all, :joins => :products,:include => :ratings, :conditions => ["product_id = ?",2086981])` ?

Comment: What are the rating_set_id's for each one of the 15 ?

Comment: 5 products belong to each rating set (Rating Sets = 40, 41, 47)

Comment: What about rating set ID 48, the one you are looking for in your query?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was looking at another query. For the rating_set 48 and product_id 2144877 I get 5 records each belongs to rating_sets 48, 52, 21.

Comment: Maybe the rating_set param should be rating_set_id or rating_id ?  If you get the name wrong it probably wouldn't actually complain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
recommendations = Recommendation.joins(:product).includes(:ratings).where(:product_id => 2086981, :rating_set => 40).all
recommendations.each do |rec|
  puts rec.ratings # this will return an array of ratings if this recommendation has ratings.
end
```

I think your `:joins => :products` should be singular: `:joins => :product` and your `:include` should be `:includes`.

**EDIT:**

New query that matches the relations in the new model code posted:

```
recommendations = Recommendation.joins(:products, :product_recommendations).includes(:ratings).where(:products => { :id => 2086981 }, : product_recommendations => { :rating_set => 40 }).all
recommendations.each do |rec|
  puts rec.ratings # this will return an array of ratings if this recommendation has ratings.
end
```

Comment: This does not work, it needs to be `products`. If I use product I get an association not found exception. And if I change it to `products` with the same query as above I get: `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'recommendations.product_id' in 'where clause': SELECT recommendations.* FROM recommendations INNER JOIN product_recommendations ON product_recommendations.recommendation_id = recommendations.id INNER JOIN products ON products.id = product_recommendations.product_id WHERE recommendations.product_id = 2086981 AND recommendations.rating_set = 40`

Comment: Your question description doesn't match your model code. "a `recommendation` `belongs_to` a `product`" but your model code has `has_many :products`. Also because your `Recommendation` model doesn't `belong_to` a `product`, you can't have the condition: `.where(:product_id => 2086981, ...` because your `Recommendation` model doesn't have a `product_id` column. I've updated my answer with a new query.

Comment: Sorry about that, updated question. The models I added are correct.

Comment: Im still getting the exception: `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column recommendations.rating_set`

Comment: I've updated the query, try it now. The error says you don't have a `rating_set` column in the `Recommendation` model so I've dropped that condition from the query. Do you have the `rating_set` column in model perhaps? The question indicates the `rating_set` column was is the `Recommendation` model.

Comment: * in _another_ model perhaps?

Comment: I have the `rating_set` column in my product_recommendations join table.

Comment: Is it possible to return an individual rating per a recommendation rather than an array of ratings?

Answer (score 0):

Is your data model actually as you have described it? Your initial description seemed to indicate that it was all parent->child (one-to-many) relations. Product has a one-to-many with Recommendation and Recommendation has a one-to-many Rating

Which would imply a table structure like this:

```
products table
:id

recommendations table
:id
:product_id

ratings table
:id
:recommendation_id
```

However, all the generated SQL queries you posted seem to show some kind of join table called `product_recommendations`. What is that?
Do you actually have a many-to-many relationship between products and recommendations with a join table called `product_recommendations`?

If so I'd say your query should work but you'll need to help Rails out a little by defining the fields not as `has_many` and `belongs_to` but `has_and_belongs_to_many` for both Product and Recommendation models.

See if this helps http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

Comment: Update with my model info.